# Finding percentage which is less

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

The number that is 50% greater than $60$ is what percentage less than the number that is 20% less than $150$ ?

My try :

I considered a number is 50% of $130$ which is greater than the $60$ and 20% of $700$ which is less than the $150$ .

But my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number that is 50% greater than 60 is 90. The number that is 20% less than 150 is 120. So you are asked, what percentage less than 120 is 90? so we solve 90=120x and we get x=75%. Thus 90 is 75% of 120, which is 25% less than 120. Thus the answer must be 25%

Comment: How did you find the 50% greater than 60 and 20% less than 150 ?

Comment: 0.5 x 60 =30. Thus 50% greater than 60 is 60+30 = 90. Similarly, 0.2 x 150 = 30. So 20% less than 150 is 150-30=120